# I am using Sample App of Bluetooth Chat.I want to search only those devices on which "BluetoothChat" is installed

Tags: bluetooth

I am using Sample App of Bluetooth Chat.I Have one problem I want to search only those devices on which "BluetoothChat" is installed. Please help I am new in android.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. All you can do is try connecting them all, if the connection is refused, you will know that this device is not running your app.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.because you did not check package name of your application in another device before connectivity via bluetooth.If you want to connect only tab or mobile device then this can easily possible.